# Multiple data file directories with different sizes

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

can you configure multiple data_file_directories with different sizes and Cassandra will manage it without issue ?

For example:
data_file_directories:
    - /data1/cassandra/data
    - /data4/cassandra/data

where data1 is 450 GB and data4 is 1 TB.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different size will not be an issue, however there are some gotchas when it comes to using multiple dirs for `data_file_directories`. I'd encourage you to read through [TLP's blog](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2018/08/22/the-fine-print-when-using-multiple-data-directories.html) that highlights most of them.

The summary is that there are bugs that hit usage of multiple data dirs in older versions of cassandra. With more modern versions there are still issues where removing one of the data directories could render the node unrecognisable to the rest of the cluster, although this is not really a bug, you are removing the system tables that store cluster membership information.

Comment: Cheers! We're on 3.11.4. Removing existing data directories is not a scenario for us.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine. Just mention all the directories in cassandra.yaml file and restart if needed.